# Determine concave point

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing

If I use the `goodFeaturesToTrack`, I can get all corner points (red, blue). However, I only want to keep the concave points (blue). I have no ideas how to implement. How can I do it?

[image]
[image]

The following image is the actual running sample:
[image]

Comment: Take the convex hull. The points that are in the convex hull are the red points; the  points that are not in the convex hull are the blue points. See [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html?#convex-hull). Note that if you use the last optional argument `returnPoints` and set it to `False`, it will just return the indices of your original points that are in the convex hull (and so you'll also know the indices of the points not in the hull).

Comment: Sorry, my explain is not detail. Actually, the above image simulate some actual situation. That is, the white area is not smooth. Therefore, convex hull may skip some point or add noise point.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Not all convex corners will be on the convex hull. In fact, you can see that in the example image.

Comment: @m69 Ah...hm, I see. And the convex hull of the inverse image as the concave points would have the same problem.

Comment: I guess in general, if you have a mask, then at each blue point (concave), more of the pixels around it will be white than black, right, since the angle will need to be < 180 degrees. You could implement that just looking in the direct neighborhood (the 8 pixels surrounding), or use a larger radius and just count the number of white vs black pixels.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I upload a simple for an actual use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems like the easy thing to do here is to convolve your image with a box filter (or similar but with an elliptical shape) which will give you windowed averages all over your image. You can simply index this convolution result at your corner points. If the convolution result at those points is more than 50%, there's more white around that point, ergo, it is a concave point. Otherwise, it is convex. Here's what that might look like in code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

# read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('example.png', 0)

# get corner points, remove duplicate/nearby points
contours = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]
contour = contours[0]
pts = np.array([contour[0]] + [pt1 for pt0, pt1 in pairwise(contour) if not (abs(pt0 - pt1) <= 1).all()])
x, y = pts[:, -1, 0], pts[:, -1, 1]

# get the kernel that you will sum around your corner points
kernel = np.float64(cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (13, 13)))
kernel /= np.sum(kernel)

# convolve the image with the kernel, and pull out the sums at the corner points
conv = cv2.filter2D(img/255, cv2.CV_64F, kernel)
neighborhood_sums = conv[y, x]

# concave indices have more white than black around them, so convolution will be >= 1/2
concave_indices = neighborhood_sums >= 0.5

# draw markers
marked = cv2.merge([img, img, img])
for pt, concave in zip(pts, concave_indices):
    color = (255, 0, 255) if concave else (0, 255, 0)
    marker = cv2.MARKER_TRIANGLE_UP if concave else cv2.MARKER_TRIANGLE_DOWN
    cv2.drawMarker(marked, tuple(pt[0]), color, markerType=marker, markerSize=10, thickness=3)
```

After the imports I defined one of the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for iterating things in pairs (e.g. `s -> (s0, s1), (s1, s2), ...`). This isn't really important at all to the problem but is just useful for me getting rid of duplicate points that were grabbed from `findContours()`. After that, the rest proceeds as previously described. You can draw your own kernel or whatever you like, but I just pulled one from `getStructuringElement()` since you can do ellipses of arbitrary size (although note that this returns a strangely shaped kernel, you could define a circle better yourself likely). Note the size of the kernel is specified in total width here, not just radius, and it's normalized by the number of 1s in it so that the result is always between 0 and 1.

And here's the result of the above on your first image:

[image: Marked concave vs convex points]

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions it to use `HIT_MISS_MORPH` in different kernels:

If you choose this kernel:

```
[[-1 -1  1]
 [-1 -1  1]
 [ 1  1  1]]
```

Then do hitmiss on the threshed image, you can get two anchors:

```
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_HITMISS, kernel, anchor=(-1,-1))
```

[image]

Draw on the origin image:

[image]

---

Found anchors in different kernels(rotate the basic kernel and|or inverse it):

[image]

Display in colors on the origin image:

[image]